# Lotus Notes 9.0.1 Fixpack 7 removes com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.library

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

When I try to reinstall latest extension library (ExtensionLibraryOpenNTF-901v00_17.20160428-0214.zip) Notes Client just says "No acceptable features were found on the selected site(s)...."

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

after applying Fixpack 7 I had to uninstall app extlib plugins and install it again

Answer (score 0):

The best way to send out addons to the client is thru widgets, super simple to add and remove/readd.

You can also install them thru a policy and publish them in the widget catalog.

http://www.xpagedeveloper.com/2016/adding-openntf-extensions-the-simple-way-into-your-client

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour occours if the plugin is disabled. Installing fix packs can cause this, but I don't know why. As long as the plugin is disabled, it is still installed and you cannot reinstall it.

You have to go to `Application > Application Management`, activate the `Show Disabled Features` switch (third icon in taskbar) and look for the disabled Extension Library feature. All manually installed features, like the Extension Library, where located in `framework\shared\eclipse`. When you select the feature, you can enable it on the right hand side or in the context menu.